# Different screen scales for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, screen, scale-mode

This have been an issuse for as long I used Ubuntu, like 2016. How to be able to combine screens with different resolutions. My laptop has a quad-hd resolution and my "large" screens have "just-hd". So to make the laptop-screen usable for text etc it's set to scale down, eg making 1 pixel take the place of four. But, i don't want that behavior on my HD-screens.

I got my hope up when I tried the settings after upgrading to 22.04 and the visual representation of my screen layout showed all tree screens with the same size... but when applying the changes it all broke down and there was the same scaling for all three screens. Is this expected to work as one would expect out of the box now or is this still a problem? Or is it my computer that has problems?